# HTML - multiselect stealing dom scroll on long forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a form system that a form can have many fields with any input type. Meaning I have text input/area, radio, checkbox, select, and select multiple.

My issue is that when scrolling the form if the mouse enters multiselect (I assume single selects will do this too) the select takes control of the mouse events so scrolling stops. You have to move your mouse out of the input to regain access to scroll which can be jaring.

I have no problem rebinding the scroll to the input once it has focus to scroll the options but I don't want it to assume it automatically.

Comment: If the multi select doesnt scroll , or loses focus, how can the user select from the available options

Comment: Unfortunately that's a native part of how multi-selects work (depending on the client you're getting a real windows list.)

If the experience truly is problematic for a large number of users you're best bet is to change whether or not there is a multiselect on the form at all or if it's enabled (keeping in mind that changes how it responds in the DOM and with screen readers).

Comment: I had solved this but forgot to re-post. This can be solved by attaching a quick function to the element and inside it handles the scroll event attaching a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we solved this problem. We attached a function to the target that watches the scroll event. The target gets a quick mask element that when scrolled the mask is shown thereby preventing the event bubble to scroll the target.

Since the outer element is being scrolled the target element will not keep the scroll event for a prolonged period of time. Attach a timeout of say 500ms will allow for the target to know that you are wanting to scroll the target.

```
function scrollUninterruptable(elem) {
var scrollTimer = null,
scrollMask = $('<div>', { 'style': 'position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;', 'class': 'scrollMask' }).hide();
elem = $(elem);
elem.append(scrollMask);
elem.parent().off('scroll.uninterruptably').on('scroll.uninterruptably', function() {
    elem.css('position', 'relative');
    scrollMask.show();
    if (scrollTimer) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    }
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        elem.css('position', '');
        scrollMask.hide();
    }, 500);
});
}
```

Again this just watches the scroll event attaches a 500ms timeout then hides the mask which will allow the scroll event to fire on the target.